# Can't write in file using C++ by tutorial

Tags: c++

Using the tutorial [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/). I can't write text into file. I don't know why, please help me.

The following is the code:

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong??? Just tested and it worked as expected, a file `example.txt` was created with the string written into it!

Comment: How do you compile this? What is the error?

Comment: @DrewDormann just for getting me better in how I should edit in the future, why did you make that edit?

Comment: You'll need to describe your problem better. This question is just someone else's working code with the message "It doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does the following fail?

Does a new file named "example.txt" get created?

Try adding a couple of cout statements in between your code to see how far you get.

```
ofstream myfile;
cout << "here 1\n"; 
myfile.open ("example.txt");
cout << "here 2\n"; 
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
cout << "here 3\n"; 
myfile.close();
cout << "here 4\n";     
return 0;
```

Your code looks just like the code in the tutorial so it should work, although I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: I know what my problem is. Actually, it did write. The problem is I print it in a wrong way. Much thanks!